# Node.js: I am struggling to store the results of a callback function into a dictionary variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, api, callback

I am trying to make a program using a website's api, but the documentation provided is very sparse, and I am really struggling to make any progress.
Here is an example of the code I am working on at the moment.

```
var arr = database.search('search query', {parameter: value}, function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

The thing is, when I write data to the console, everything works fine. It prints a paginated dictionary of dictionaries with all the data that I need. Here's the problem...

If I try to replace the code in the middle of the block with something like `return data`, or try to store it in a variable like `arr = data;`, I do not get all the data that gets logged to the console.

What I'd like to happen is  to be able to store the results of this search into a dictionary object so that I can use the data in my program. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which dictionary are you putting this into? Note that in ES6 it's `let` not `var`.

Comment: Well I think that the data that comes from this search query function is a dictionary object, so I was trying to store that into a variable I created called "arr". Sorry if this is not a clear answer, I am pretty new to node js.

Comment: As a general rule the return value of functions with callback arguments is usually just garbage and can't be used. You need to do any assignment within the callback itself.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell that I can't add a comment here, but I think it is an async problem?
Assume it is an async problem, meaning that database.search runs asynchronously

```
let savedData
var arr = database.search('search query', {parameter: value}, function(err, data){
    console.log("data returned =",data);
    savedData = data
});
console.log("savedData =", savedData)
```

If you do it this way, you can't get any data logged for savedData in the console as the process is async. The console.log for savedData is triggered before assigning the data to savedData, but indeed the savedData store the data returned.

But if you log the savedData inside the callback function, you should get all your data

```
 let savedData
    var arr = database.search('search query', {parameter: value}, function(err, data){
        console.log("data returned =",data);
        savedData = data;
        console.log("savedData =", savedData)
    });
```

please give me more information to identify the problem, thanks

Comment: I spoke too soon. I am using your exact code (for now), the only thing I changed was that I got rid of "var arr = ". If I comment out the top console log, and move the bottom console log outside of the search code block, I get "undefined" as a result. Is the savedData inside of the search query a local variable that's getting overwritten by the global variable outside the search function?

Comment: The key here is the `let` outside of the function which provides a spot for the data to go. If you don't do that you lose the local variable.

Comment: Yeah I made savedData a global variable by defining it right above the search method call. I just did a test that gave me different results. So inside the search method code block, I have this line 'savedData = data;'. If I put this line of code inside the block 'console.log(typeof savedData);' I get "object" printed. However, if I put that very same line of code outside of the code block I get "undefined" printed. I do not understand why the data is only being stored whilst inside the code block.

Comment: it's is because the code and the function inside database.search runs asynchronously. I am working and I will try to explain in more details later

Comment: Do I need to just write all my code within this block of code? If I use ```console.log(savedData.results[0].style);``` it prints the data I need. I am really confused about the whole "asynchronous" thing. I would like to just get the data I need and exit the code block

Comment: After doing a little research, I think I understand what it means for that code to be asynchronous. So, now that I understand that, what do I need to do to about storing this data? Is it common for JS coders to do all their code inside a callback function block? I am able to get the data I need, but I'd like to be able to continue to manipulate that data with other functions that are outside that block of code.